# Logic gates in a schematic

Tags: circuit-design, schematics, logic-gates

The following is an example of a Logic-And gate using two spst switches:

[image]

[image]

What is the most common schematic to show a logic-and gate (without the symbol itself)? I have come across various schematics showing input nodes A and B (with nothing connected to it), but I'm not sure how those would be shown in a schematic to simulate the on/off states of those inputs. Additionally, how does one usually show that a logic gate's output is either in the On or Off position, or is this usually not done in a schematic (I've used an LED below but this is more to show myself that the and-operation is working correctly).

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Aaarrrgggh! Earth symbols should be pointing to the Earth. The symbol represents metal plates buried in the ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the most common schematic to show a logic-and gate (without the symbol itself)?

[image]

*Figure 1. Function Block Diagram (FBD) is popular in some PLC programming languages, with Germans particularly fond of it. Image source: [Science Direct](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/function-block-diagram).*

> I have come across various schematics showing input nodes A and B (with nothing connected to it), but I'm not sure how those would be shown in a schematic to simulate the on/off states of those inputs.

I think we'd need an example from you.

> Additionally, how does one usually show that a logic gate's output is either in the On or Off position, ...

[image]

*Figure 2. Siemens LOGO! program status monitoring. (Click for full-scale view.) Image source: [Treffpunkt Eltern](http://www.treffpunkteltern.de/foren/viewtopic.php?p=301223).*

In this example logic status is indicated by colour.